# How to extract Date Only

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

When using 
`test = new Date()` ,

on doing  `console.log ('test')` I get

`"Thu Sep 12 2013 17:55:25 GMT+0545 (NPT)"`. I need to take only `"Thu Sep 12 2013"`.
On doing these  `(new Date()).getDay()` it does not work for me.
Help me out guys.
Thank you in advace !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
test = new Date()

console.log(test.toDateString())
```

from: http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/todatestring